# How do add random array values together into another array and then display them while counting how many values appear? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, dice

I wanted to simulate rolling two dice using a random number generator from 1 to 6 and then add those two values together and I am required to set this in a loop that it does this a million times. After I have acquired the values I need to display how many sums of each number appears. How would I do this? Am I on the right track? I keep getting my core dumped so I think it's a memory issue.

Here is the text that I am suppose to follow:
"Suppose you have a game where you roll two dice, that follow these rules:
Roll 1-11: Get that value
Roll 12: Reroll and add one to the value
The “roll 12” rule can be hit multiple times. For example, if you roll (6,6) then (6,6) then (1,1),
your total value for that game will be 4 (as 1+1+2=4). Write a program that simulates one iteration of this game.
Then write a loop that runs this game 1,000,000 times, keeping track of how many of each value you saw, then display the results showing every value and what percent of the time you got that value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{ 
    int i, k, l, y, ncount;
    k=0;
    l=0;
    y=0;
    int R[1000000];
    int T[1000000];
    int S[1000000];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    {
        R[k] = (rand() % 6 + 1);
        T[l] = (rand() % 6 + 1);
        S[y] = R[k] + T[l];
        k++;
        l++;
        y++;
    }


    ncount = count (S, S+1000000, 1);
    cout << "1 appears " << ncount << " times.\n";



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're running out of stack memory simply. These are pretty big arrays. Try using `std::vector<int>` instead, to manage that large amount of memory in the dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: How would I go about changing the arrays to a vector?

Comment: Something like `std::vector<int> R(100000);`. Check the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I interpret this assignment, it does not require a large array.

> Then write a loop that runs this game 1,000,000 times, keeping track of how many of each value you saw,

Notice that you do not keep track of every value you saw; you merely keep track of *how many times* you saw it.

Moreover, the value you have to count is only the final value after you have "played" the game once, that is, rolled two dice repeatedly until you get something that is not double sixes. In the example you were given, rolling (6,6), then (6,6), then (1,1), those three rolls of the two dice are just one game, whose final value is 4. Therefore, after all these rolls you would add 1 to the number of times you have seen 4.

The data storage for this game only needs to store one integer for each value you might get at the end of a game. The bad news is that the game has no maximum theoretical value--in theory it is possible that you might roll (6,6) any number of times one right after the other, resulting in a high value for the game.
In practice, however, it is very unlikely that you will roll double sixes more than a few times in a row.

One well-known way to keep count of the number of times each value has occurred, when the range of possible values that may actually occur is not too large, is to allocate an array a little larger than the largest value you have to count. If you name the array `count`, then `count[2]` is the number of times a 2 has occurred, `count[3]` is the number of times a 3 has occurred, etc.
(This is not so convenient if you have to count how many times a negative number occurs, but you don't have to worry about that in this case.)

Other ways include data structures where you keep pairs of numbers: the first number of each pair is a value, the second is how many times the first number has occurred. The data structure could be anything that can store pairs of numbers: a linked list you designed yourself, an `std::list`, or an `std::map`.
But each time you "play" a game you have to search your data structure to see if the value of that game has occurred before, and then either add 1 to the number of times that value has occurred, or make a new pair of numbers in your data structure to count the first occurrence of that value.

> then display the results showing every value and what percent of the time you got that value.

In other words, showing every *different* value *once,* along the percentage of games that had that value.
But it is generally not good practice to write some lines of code specifically for each value you want to print, the way you did in your example to show
how many times the value 1 occurs.

---

By the way, be sure to read the description of the game carefully.
Your initial attempt to program this will never produce the value 13, but the game can result in the value 13, or even 14 or higher.
For example, rolls of (6,6), then (6,6), then (6,5) make one game with a value of 1 + 1 + 11 = 13.

Another recommendation: do not create a multitude of differently-named
variables that you do not really need.
In your initial attempt at this program you have variables `k`, `l`, and `y`
whose only use is to index the arrays `R`, `S`, and `T`.
*Never once* when you use any of these variables for these purposes
will the value of any of these variables be different from `i`.
Your loop would have been better written

```
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
{
    R[i] = (rand() % 6 + 1);
    T[i] = (rand() % 6 + 1);
    S[i] = R[i] + T[i];
}
```

That loop does *exactly* what your loop does, but it is much clearer what it
actually does do when you see it in this form.

As explained above, however, much better still is not to write the loop
this way at all: you do want the `for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)`
but not the stuff inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions especially the loop one because I thought I had to create a difference variable for each array! I have used vectors instead now so I don't get the core dumped issue, but I'm a little stuck on the reroll part. I noticed that 1 never occurs after posting this...!

Comment: There are good hints in sehe's answer. Notice how sehe wrote a function to play the game once: `magic_roll()` will return the value at the end of a single game. And then sehe calls `magic_roll()` one time within each iteration of a loop `for (size_t i = 0; i < 1'000'000; ++i)`. There is also a loop within `magic_roll()` to deal with the re-rolling. So when `magic_roll()` occurs within a loop, you really have a loop within a loop.

Comment: Now that you mentioned all of those hints, I have figured out this assignment! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I liked this - quite cute - experiment.

Here's a sample bit of code you cannot use (it uses all kinds of library stuff and C++14 goodness that your course will definitely not allow, statistically speaking, and which would raise a good number of eyebrows if you turned it in).

However it can serve as inspiration and to validate your bias-free random number generation and correct statistics!

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/252cff02071ffa52)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

namespace ba  = boost::accumulators;
namespace bat = ba::tag;

using namespace std;

static mt19937 engine { random_device{}() };
static uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> dist(1, 6);

auto single() {
    return dist(engine);
}

auto dual() { 
    auto a = single(), b = single();
    //cout << "Rolled (" << a << ", " << b << ")\n";

    return a + b;
}

auto magic_roll() {
    int eyes, extra = 0;
    while (12 == (eyes=dual()))
        extra += 1;

    return extra + eyes;
}

int main() {
    ba::accumulator_set<unsigned, ba::stats<bat::mean, bat::variance> > stats;
    constexpr auto N = 15;
    size_t histo[N] = { 0 }; // allow for quite extreme outliers

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1'000'000; ++i) {
        auto score = magic_roll();
        //cout << "score: " << score << "\n";
        stats(score);
        assert(score >= 2 && score < N);
        ++histo[score];
    }

    cout << "Mean:          " << ba::mean(stats) << "\n";
    cout << "Std Deviation: " << sqrt(ba::variance(stats)) << "\n";

    auto peak = *max_element(begin(histo), end(histo));
    auto scale = [peak](auto v) { return v * 60.0 / peak; };

    auto bucket = 0;
    for(auto v : histo)
    {
        cout << "Histo bucket: " << right
            << setw(2) << bucket++ << "\t" 
            << setw(6) << v << " " << string(scale(v), '*') << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output

```
Mean:          6.88604
Std Deviation: 2.29999
Histo bucket:  0         0 
Histo bucket:  1         0 
Histo bucket:  2     27806 *********
Histo bucket:  3     56229 *******************
Histo bucket:  4     84624 *****************************
Histo bucket:  5    113481 ***************************************
Histo bucket:  6    142361 **************************************************
Histo bucket:  7    170696 ************************************************************
Histo bucket:  8    143744 **************************************************
Histo bucket:  9    114814 ****************************************
Histo bucket: 10     86860 ******************************
Histo bucket: 11     57734 ********************
Histo bucket: 12      1611 
Histo bucket: 13        39 
Histo bucket: 14         1
```

Comment: This is very interesting even though I have no idea what that advanced coding works! I hope that some day later in the future when I get better I will be able to write something amazing as you! I also will not turn this in because it would be obvious and I am a beginner! Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Thank you again for all of your hints!